# send predefined email templates via phpmailer

Tags: php, html, email, templates, phpmailer

Sorry for the repeated questions. I haven't figured it out to solve this problem.

My Question:

I have a form to send both predefined and custom written templates to the user.
In that form, I've got a select option to select templates to showup in the given textarea field. If you select predefined templates then you can get an preview on the textarea. if you select custom template then you can write your text in the textarea.

I have implemented till this step both using phpmailer and normal php mail function.

After the preview, I have to send that current viewable template in the textarea to the user.

I've tried with php mail program, it does send mail without images and url tags. I can view plain text with tables. That's it.

When I try with phpmailer, I could send full html content using 
`$body = file_get_contents('template-1.html');`.

If I use this then I can send only one template. I need to write if else condition for the selected template to be sent to users.

Could anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: phpmailer's job is to send email. it's not a template engine, nor should it ever be. If you want templates, then YOU have to write the code to load them and feed them into phpmailer for sending out.

Comment: @MarcB, I want to know how can I load the selected templates to the $body. could you please tell me that, if possible.

Comment: So removing all the cruft, the real question seems to be "how can I load a file based off a user's selection?".  Is that correct?

Comment: @Mr.Llama, Both are correct. Your point of view is correct when I use the above code to get contents from html page.   If I use normal post to send the mail, It sends only text. if the normal post is working, I don't need to use the file_get_contents('template-1.html');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of information in the question, this is mostly a wild guess as to what's wanted! It sounds like a pretty basic problem.

On your page you have an HTML `select` element that lets you pick a template. I'll assume this value ends up in `$_POST['template']`

```
<select name="template">
<option value="template-1">Template 1</option>
<option value="template-2">Template 2</option>
<option value="template-3">Template 3</option>
</select>
```

Then in your script, use that value to load the appropriate template:

```
$templates = array('template-1', 'template-2', 'template-3');
//Validate selection
if (in_array($_POST['template'], $templates)) {
    $body = file_get_contents($_POST['template'].'.html');
} else {
    die ('No template selected');
}
//...now get on with sending...
```

That help?

Comment: This is what I wanted to implement. But, I am getting no template selected at all time.

Comment: You did wrap that `select` in a `form` tag, right? Try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to see what you are submitting from your form.